# Экспорт словаря в Html файл из другого файла python

Tags: python, html, импорт, export

*У меня есть словарь:*
**`slovar_milk = {'Name':'Milk','Ves':1500,'Cetegory':'Milk Products','Price':67,'Godnost':7,'Volume':1000}`**

*Мне нужно его экспортировать в html файл,* ***но from _____ import * не работает в html.***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    #Здесь должен быть словарь, но его обязательно нужно импортировать из другого файла. 
    #Если бы from import работало, то это бы выглядело так: from APP_3.vievs import *
</body> 
</body>
</html>
```

**Помогите, пожалуйста!**

Answer (score 1):

Преобразовываете словарь в JSON с помощью Python и записываете в файл name_file.json. Далее читаете с помощью Javascript файл name_file.json и преобразовываете его в объект Javascript. Далее вставляете данные из javascript в html.

Comment: а если я не знаю javascript

Comment: @Лев Это печально. Потому, что только javascript-у позволено манипулировать с html.